# Stokes' Theorem with several boundary curves and confusion about the notion of boundaries

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, stokes-theorem

I am asked to calculate $\begin{gather*} \iint_S \nabla\times\vec{A} \end{gather*}$,

$\vec{A}=(z,x,y)$ and S the surface defined by $x^2 + y^2 + z^2= 1, ~~~~0\leq z \leq1/2.$

This is meant to compare the flux and the circulation of $\vec{A}$ over the boundary. We have been taught Stokes' theorem at a very basic level, since we aren't taking pure maths. Most examples involve simple surfaces that seem to 'close', like a paraboloid $z=x^2 +y^2$, or a pyramid and its base.

In all of them, we only used *one* curve along which to calculate the circulation, but apparently here two are needed: the level sets $z=0$ and $z=1/2$ of the sphere. I don't understand why, since one of the curves could be used to bound the surface. What am I missing?

I found in this page http://www.math.toronto.edu/courses/mat237y1/20189/notes/Chapter5/S5.6.html the definition for the boundary points. So it makes sense in this case... but what if we don't know what is $S_0$? I feel like there's some sort of simplification there. What is a true definition for boundary curves of surfaces?

Also, it doesn't explain why the direction of circulation of both curves must be opposite in order to calculate the flux over the surface. One could interpret it as "subtracting" the flux between $1/2\leq z \leq 1$ and $ 0 \leq z\leq 1/2$, but again it looks a bit fishy.

This post [Stokes' theorem on surface with boundary being a union of closed, simple, piecewise smooth curves](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3305460/stokes-theorem-on-surface-with-boundary-being-a-union-of-closed-simple-piecew) seems related, but it's using precisely the aforementioned approach.

Comment: Both curves comprise the boundary. Just as the boundary of a rectangle consists of four line segments, when you roll the rectangle into a cylinder (attach two opposite sides), you are left with two circles. Actually do this with a piece of paper and you can figure out the orientations of the two circles.

Answer (score 1):

To start with, the sphere all by itself, as defined by the equation $x^2+y^2+z^2=1$ has no boundary at all.

Let's restrict the sphere to the region where $z \ge 0$. Then indeed, as you say, the resulting surface has just one curve on its boundary, namely the curve where the sphere intersects the plane $z=0$, which forms a circle $x^2+y^2=1$ in the $z=0$ plane. Let me denote that circle $C_0$. Visually, imagine slicing the sphere along the $z=0$ plane, throwing away everything below that, and keeping what's above it.

If on the other hand we could restrict the sphere to the region where $z \le 1/2$. Then again the resulting surface has just one curve on its boundary namely the curve where the sphere intersects the plane $z=1/2$, which forms a circle $x^2 + y^2 + (1/2)^2 = 1$ in that plane; we can simplify that to $x^2+y^2 = 3/4$ in the $z=1/2$ plane. Let me denote that circle $C_{1/2}$. Visually, imaging slicing the sphere along the $z=1/2$ plane, throwing away everything above that plane, and keeping what's below.

But when you form a surface by restricting the sphere to the region where $0 \le z \le 1/2$, then the resulting surface has two boundary circles: $C_0$ and $C_{1/2}$. Imagine slicing the sphere simultaneously along the $z=0$ and $z=1/2$ planes, throwing away what's below $z=0$ and also throwing away above $z=1/2$, and keeping what's between. Using just *one* of those curves will not get you the whole boundary.

Comment: How can a sphere have no boundary? Wouldn't it be precisely $C_0$? Also, it seems like both surfaces should be traversed in opposite directions. I don't get this either. It feels like sort of taking the limits of one variable calculus, so as to remove the flux of the areas you aren't interested in. Is this a correct interpretation?

Comment: @JaimeYepesdePaz I find you are mixing the notions of a sphere and a ball. The ball has a boundary, which is the sphere. The latter has no boundary.

Comment: I would say intuitively that the sphere would have a boundary too: any circular curve that surrounds it, like a sort of belt. Doesn't it work like that?

Comment: No the boundary of a surface is not like a belt. Instead, it's like an edge. The entire sphere, described in my first paragraph, has no edge at all, i.e. no boundary at all. The hemisphere, described in my second paragraph, as circular edge, namely the $C_0$. Your surface, describe in my final paragraph, has two circular edges, namely the circles $C_0$ and $C_{1/2}$.

Comment: One more thing: if Stoke's Theorem is your first exposure to vector calculus, I might suggest you first study [Green's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Green%27s_theorem), which has most of the same ideas except in the simpler setting of the 2-dimensional plane, rather than 3-dimensional space.

Comment: I don't get the difference between edge and belt. Formally, I've seen that the boundary is the set of points in which, taking a ball centered at them, you have points of the surface $S$ , *and* points of the surface $S_0$ in which $S$ is embedded. This makes sense for my original case and also explains why a sphere doesn't have such a curve. But what if I only take the upper half of the sphere? I understood 'being embedded' as the surface being the intersection of $S_0$ with other things. In this last case, however, there needn't be a $S_0$, which could be the whole sphere.

Comment: Regarding your "Formally" sentence in the last comment, if you have seen a formal definition of the boundary of a surface, and if that definition is what you are having trouble understanding, then you could make your question much easier to answer if you hit the edit button and gave a clear statement of that definition in your post.

Comment: Beyond that, I can't make much sense of the rest of your comment. I've already explained that the boundary of the upper half of the sphere is the curve $C_0$. I don't know what $S_0$ means to you.